# PostgreSQL query returning multiple rows instead of one

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, operator-precedence, rails-postgresql

I have two tables: `user` and `projects`, with a one-to-many relationship between two.
`projects` table has field `status` with project statuses of the user.

`status` can be one of:

```
launched, confirm, staffed, overdue, complete, failed, ended
```

I want to categorize users in two categories:

1. users having projects in `launched` phase
2. users having projects other than `launched` status.

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.*), CASE 
    WHEN p.status = 'LAUNCHED' THEN 1
    ELSE 2
    END as user_category
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN projects p ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE (LOWER(u.username) like '%%%'
    OR LOWER(u.personal_intro) like '%%%'
    OR LOWER(u.location) like '%%%'
    OR u.account_status != 'DELETED'
AND system_role=10 AND u.account_status ='ACTIVE')
ORDER BY set_order, u.page_hits DESC
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

I am facing **duplicate records** for following scenario:

If user has projects with status `launched` as well as `overdue`, `complete` or `failed`, then that user is recorded two times as both the conditions in `CASE` are satisfying for that user.

Please suggest a query where a user that has any project in `launched` status gets his `user_category` set to `1`. The same user should not be repeated for `user_category 2`.

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function.

Answer (score 4):

The query is probably not doing what you think it does for a number of reasons

- There is `DISTINCT` and there is `DISTINCT`**`ON`**`(col1, col2)`.
  `DISTINCT (u.*)` is no different from `DISTINCT u.*`. The parentheses are just noise.
- `AND` binds before `OR` according to [**operator precedence**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE). I suspect you want to use parentheses around the conditions `OR`'ed together? Or do you need it the way it is? But you don't need parentheses around the whole `WHERE` clause in any case.
- Your expression `LOWER(u.username) LIKE '%%%'` doesn't make any sense. Every non-null string qualifies. Can be replaced with `u.username IS NOT NULL`. I suspect you want something different?
- Postgres is **case sensitive** in string handling. You write of `status` being 'launched' etc. but use 'LAUNCHED' in your query. Which is it?
- A couple of table qualifications are missing from the question making it ambiguous for the reader. I filled in as I saw fit.

Everything put together, it *might* work like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.set_order, u.page_hits, u.id)
       u.*
     , CASE WHEN p.status = 'LAUNCHED' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS user_category
FROM   users         u
LEFT   JOIN projects p ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE  LOWER(u.username)       LIKE '%%%' -- ???
    OR LOWER(u.personal_intro) LIKE '%%%'
    OR LOWER(u.location)       LIKE '%%%'

    OR u.account_status != 'DELETED'      -- with original logic
   AND u.system_role = 10
   AND u.account_status = 'ACTIVE'
ORDER  BY u.set_order, u.page_hits DESC, u.id, user_category
LIMIT  10
```

Detailed explanation in this related question:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Two [`EXISTS` semi-joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) instead of the `DISTINCT ON` and `CASE` might be faster:

```
SELECT u.*
     , CASE WHEN EXISTS (
          SELECT FROM projects p
          WHERE p.user_id = u.id AND p.status = 'LAUNCHED')
       THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS user_category
FROM   users u
WHERE
    (  LOWER(u.username)       LIKE '%%%' -- ???
    OR LOWER(u.personal_intro) LIKE '%%%'
    OR LOWER(u.location)       LIKE '%%%'
    OR u.account_status != 'DELETED'      -- with alternative logic?
    )
AND    u.system_role = 10  -- assuming it comes from users ???
AND    u.account_status = 'ACTIVE'
AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM projects p WHERE p.user_id = u.id)
ORDER  BY u.set_order, u.page_hits DESC
LIMIT  10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MIN()` on your `CASE` result, and it seems dropping the DISTINCT would be a wise choice:

```
SELECT u.*, MIN(CASE 
WHEN p.status = 'LAUNCHED' THEN 1
ELSE 2
END) as user_category
...
GROUP BY <list all columns in the users table>
...
```

Since "launched" gives a 1, using MIN() will not only force a single result but will also give preference to "launched" over the other states.

Comment: I don't think this would suffice to fix the mess.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Why do you think that? It seems pretty staightforward to me.

Comment: If you drop the `DISTINCT` (and fix the other issues) `GROUP BY` would be a sensible alternative.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter agreed distinct seems wrong - I've edited my answer to drop it. To be honest, I skimmed the query and thought of this approach. There are more problems as you have pointed out I your answer

Comment: Yeah, the principal is sound now. I like the basic approach. +1 (Make that "<columns in **u** >" and actually declare the alias?)